What is an intuitive explanation for the East-West component of the Coriolis Force?
There are three components to the Coriolis force as it applies to a fired bullet. I intuitively understand two of them but not the third.
The first component is the familiar North-South component, which is the most often explained. When an object changes latitude, it retains its angular velocity while the angular velocity of the Earth changes, so the Earth essentially moves under the traveling object at a different speed.

The second component is the Up-Down component, which is also known as the Eotvos force. It is caused when an object moves East or West, and appears as a difference in local gravity (West, lower gravity; East, higher gravity). It is caused by the actual path that the object travels being shorter (Westward) or longer (Eastward) as the destination moves closer or farther from the origin.
The third component is the East-West component. When an object travels on the same latitude, it is deflected in the same amount as if it were to change longitude. That is the Coriolis force tangential to the surface of the Earth is independent of the cardinal direction of travel. I for the life of me cannot figure out the intuitive explanation of why an object fired to the East or West would be deflected North or South (to the right in the northern hemisphere. I have read many explanations:
https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/14529
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/730504/364946
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/52509/364946
The issue I have in understanding is statements such as this: "The wind moving East begins to expand its radius, thus moving outwards. Gravity pulls it back, and the wind moves South, in order to maintain the larger radius required for its increased velocity." or this "Eastward-bound objects will try to go straight out, but as shown in the diagram to the left, they will head for the equator as the best way to increase their radius out from the axis." https://stratus.ssec.wisc.edu/courses/gg101/coriolis/coriolis.html
Wind does not have intent. What causes the change in latitude (specifically for a projectile)? I understand the rightward deflection in the northern hemisphere  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force#Bounced_ball), but that does not explain a change in latitude. In this ball example, the ball begins and ends at the same latitude.
I think the closest I have made it to understanding is with this example: https://www.eyrie.org/~dvandom/Edu/newcor.html#:~:text=As%20a%20result%20of%20gravity,to%20the%20south%2C%20for%20example. Would it be accurate to say that an Eastward fired projectile has extra travel time (due to Eotvos), and so continues its rightward trajectory for a longer time and travels past its original latitude? And that a Westward fired projectile has less time and so doesn't return to its original latitude?


Based on Cleonis's answer, I think think this is the correct answer. I have made the following diagram.

Each circle is a different latitude. In a non-rotating context, the arc path of the bullet passes through higher latitudes before falling back to the original latitude. The rotation then adds an additional eastward force vector to the bullet. When firing Westward, that Eastward force vector makes the bullet stop early from returning to its original latitude. When firing Eastward, the additional Eastward vector from rotation makes the projectile overshoot its initial target and continue-on to a lower latitude.
This example assumes that the stopping point, target, or destination is the ground. This assumption is important because if the bullet misses its target, a Westward fired bullet will likely be fast enough to continue to a lower latitude that the original target (albeit at a lower velocity and higher latitude than an Eastward fired bullet).
This diagram and example differ from Cleonis's answer because his examples are for a projectile that starts with a trajectory that is tangential to the latitude at the origin. This diagram assumes that the target and the origin are at the same latitude, which requires the original trajectory to point to a higher latitude.

This might help - Coriolis Force: Direction Perpendicular to Rotation Axis Visualization

That was a really good intuitive example of the North-South Coriolis force in action! However, I need an intuitive example to understand the Coriolis force's action for an object in the East-West direction.

Try this one - Trying to gain better intuition about fictitious forces

That is a great explanation of the relationship between the acceleration and the radius; however, it does not address the meat of the question, which is how a change in rotational radius of a projectile causes a change in latitude. Specifically, why does an object moving East to West deflect North instead of just crashing into the ground at the same latitude?

In this answer, I will first set up a number of necessary concepts. With those in place, I will discuss the dynamics in the section titled: 'The dynamics'.
I will then proceed to give a dynamical derivation of the acceleration relative to the rotating coordinate system.

To understand the east-west component, I recommend the approach of John Marshall and R. Alan Plumb.
It's a series of pages that accompanies a textbook on atmospheric and oceanic dynamics written by Marshall and Plumb.
As a conceptual model for the dynamics of buoyant mass in motion over the surface of the rotating Earth, they use a turntable with a surface having a parabolic cross-section. The turntable surface is very shallow. The construction is described on the page Construction of parabolic turntable
A disk with a rim, diameter of about a meter, is filled with a resin that will slowly set, and rotation of the disk is started at 10 revolutions per minute.
Due to the rotation, the still-fluid resin redistributes to a concave shape. The fluid's final state is referred to as 'solid body rotation'. The final state has the property that everywhere the slope of the surface provides the required centripetal force to remain in an overall co-rotating state.
Over the course of hours, the resin cures. The last step to prepare for demonstration is to sand the surface to a smooth finish.
About the resulting shape:
for sustained co-rotating motion, the required centripetal force is proportional to the square of angular velocity and in linear proportion to the radial distance. That is, twice the radial distance, twice the amount of centripetal force required.

Forces on a parabolic dish
The image is an animated GIF consisting of three frames. The blue arrow represents gravity, while the red arrow represents the force of buoyancy. Note that the buoyancy force is always perpendicular to the local surface.
To demonstrate the motion of an object over that dish, a small disk of frozen carbon dioxide is released. The sublimating carbon dioxide creates a gas cushion so that the motion has very little friction.
Due to the slope, the buoyancy force is not exactly opposite in direction to the force of gravity. That not-exactly opposite gives a resultant force, which provides the required centripetal force.
The following diagram goes towards explaining why the rotating parabolic dish model is analogous to the rotating Earth.

Forces on a rotating celestial body
The Earth has an equatorial bulge due to its rotation.
In the diagram, the equatorial bulge is very much exaggerated for the purpose of demonstration.
(In the case of the actual Earth, the polar radius is $6357 \ \text{km}$, and the equatorial radius is $6378 \ \text{km}$. The difference is about $21 \ \text{km}$.)
Blue arrow: gravity
Red arrow: buoyancy force
Green arrow: resultant force of gravity and buoyancy force.

The following animation presents a case of motion over the surface of the parabolic dish, simplified to the barest essentials.

Motion over the surface of a parabolic dish
For a more vivid display, the speed is exaggerated.
The arrow represents centripetal force, arising from the slope of the surface.
The animation represents the case that the object, represented as a black dot, has a velocity relative to the rotating system. There is an oscillation of radial distance and an oscillation of angular velocity. The centripetal force is in linear proportion to the radial distance, which means it is a force according to Hooke's law. When the force that is acting is according to Hooke's law, the resulting motion is harmonic oscillation.
In the animation, the display on the left-hand side represents motion relative to the inertial coordinate system. The display on the right-hand side represents the motion as seen from a co-rotating point of view.
The following parametric equation describes the motion:
$$ x = a \cos(\Omega t) \quad \text{and} \quad y = b \sin(\Omega t),$$
where
$a$ is half the length of the major axis
$b$ is half the length of the minor axis
$\Omega$ is $360^\circ$ divided by the duration of one revolution.


The dynamics
With all of the above in place, we can consider the dynamics of the motion as represented in the motion-over-the-surface animation.
I will divide the description into 4 stages:

At the point of largest radial distance, the object is circumnavigating slower than the rotation rate of the system. So, at that stage, there is a surplus of centripetal force, and subsequently, the object is pulled closer to the axis of rotation.
As the object is pulled closer to the axis of rotation, it picks up speed because the centripetal force is doing work.
At the point of the smallest radial distance, the object is circumnavigating faster than the rotation rate of the system. At that speed, there is not enough centripetal force to keep the object at that radial distance, and due to the object's momentum, it will overshoot, and the radial distance will increase again.
As the radial distance increases again, the object loses velocity because the centripetal force is slowing it down.



All of the considerations above transfer to the case of motion of buoyant mass over the surface of the Earth.
When air mass is flowing in west-to-east direction, then that air mass is circumnavigating the Earth's axis at a slightly faster rate than the Earth itself is rotating. We have that the centripetal force arising from the slope of the Earth's surface is precisely the amount required for co-rotating motion. The air mass flowing in west-to-east direction will swing wide, so it will tend to deviate from the latitude line it is flowing along towards the Equator.
Conversely, when the air mass is flowing in east-to-west direction, it is circumnavigating the Earth's axis at a slightly slower rate than the Earth itself is rotating. Now, there is a surplus of centripetal force, and that surplus will pull the moving air mass to the inside of the latitude circle that the air mass is flowing along.

(Another way to visualize the cases of west-to-east and east-to-west motion: think of a road circuit with steeply banked corners (Example: the banked corner of the test track operated by the tyre manufacturer Continental; the Contidrome.) Let a car be going along a steeply banked corner. If the car is going too slow for the incline of the banked corner, then the car will tend to slump down the incline. Too fast: the car will tend to drift wide.)


The following is crucial:
In the case of the parabolic dish model and the actual Earth, the required centripetal force is provided by the resultant of gravity and buoyancy force. Here, I am using the expression 'buoyancy force' in the widest possible meaning. Layers of air mass are carried by layers of air mass beneath it. Ultimately, weight is carried by the Earth.
By contrast, when you throw an object such that it proceeds in ballistic motion then there is no buoyancy force; the motion is affected by gravity only (with optional consideration of friction effect).
This distinction is essential: the motion of a buoyant object will not be the same as that of a ballistic object because the buoyant object is subject to both gravity and buoyancy force, whereas the motion of a ballistic is affected by gravity only.

This means that it's not a good idea to try and use visualizations of ballistic motion to help you understand the motion of air mass over the surface of the Earth. Those are different cases: depending on the specific circumstances, the motion can come out sort of the same or in the opposite direction; you can definitely not rely on it.



Acceleration relative to the rotating system
In this section, I will derive an expression for the magnitude of the acceleration relative to the rotating system for an object that is subject to a centripetal force, with the force profile as a function of distance according to Hooke's law.
Repeating the parametric equation that describes the motion relative to the inertial coordinate system:
$$x = a \cos(\Omega t) \quad \text{and} \quad y = b \sin(\Omega t).$$
The parametric equation can be rearranged as follows:
$$ x = \frac{a+b}{2} \cos(\Omega t) + \frac{a-b}{2} \cos(\Omega t) $$
$$ y = \frac{a+b}{2} \sin(\Omega t) - \frac{a-b}{2} \sin(\Omega t).$$
After transformation of the motion to the rotating coordinate system, the motion relative to the co-rotating coordinate system is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{a-b}{2} \cos(2 \Omega t) \\
y &= - \frac{a-b}{2} \sin(2 \Omega t).
\end{align}$$
Notice that the motion along the small circle (the motion relative to the co-rotating coordinate system) cycles with a frequency of $2\Omega$.
I will refer to the motion depicted on the right-hand side of the animated GIF as 'motion along the epi-circle'.

The next step is to obtain an expression for the acceleration of the moving object relative to the co-rotating coordinate system.
Let $a_c$ be the acceleration relative to the co-rotating coordinate system.
We take advantage of the fact that the motion along the epi-circle is, in the idealized case, a perfectly circular motion.
In the case of circular motion, the acceleration is perpendicular to the velocity and has this magnitude:
$$ a_c = \omega^2r. \tag{1} \label{eq:1}$$
(I use the lowercase $\omega$ here for the motion along the epi-circle to distinguish it from the uppercase $\Omega$ that I used for the angular velocity of the system.)
As stated earlier, the motion along the epi-circle occurs at twice the frequency of the angular velocity of the system: $\omega = 2\Omega$.
Inserting that into \eqref{eq:1}:
$$ a_c = (2\Omega)^2r \tag{2}\label{eq:2}. $$
Let $v_c$ be the velocity of the object relative to the co-rotating coordinate system. We have the general relation $v=\omega r$. We have, in this case, $\omega=2\Omega$. Combining that gives for this case the expression $ 2\Omega r = v_c$, that we can use to modify \eqref{eq:2}.
After substituting, we obtain the following expression for the acceleration of the object with respect to the co-rotating coordinate system:
$$ a_c = 2\Omega v_c. \tag{3}\label{eq:3} $$

Discussion:
About the three factors in \eqref{eq:3}:
The factor $\Omega$ - the rotation rate of the overall system - is there because of a remarkable symmetry associated with Hooke's law: when the centripetal force is according to Hooke's law, then any circumnavigating motion, circular or ellipse-shaped, has the same period.
The factor $v_c$, velocity relative to the rotating system, is there because the acceleration relative to the rotating coordinate system is proportional to the radius of the corresponding epi-circle.
The factor $2$ also arises from a symmetry of motion, according to Hooke's law, because for every cycle of the overall rotation, the motion relative to the rotating coordinate system goes through its epi-circle cycle twice.



Discussion:
Ballistics
When a projectile is fired, how will it proceed?
As always, first, simplify down to a level where the phenomenon of interest is still there, but factors that do not impact the essence are omitted.
Once a projectile is underway, its motion is subject to gravity only. We can think of the motion of a projectile as orbital motion, except the velocity is way too slow and so close to the Earth that the projectile impacts the Earth's surface in a matter of seconds. However, that doesn't detract from the fact that during that short flight, the dynamics of the motion is the dynamics of orbital motion.
To simplify, we go to the case of orbital motion with constant height above the Earth.
Side remark: for orbital motion, the oblate shape of the Earth has some effect, but for the purpose of this discussion, that particular effect is negligibly small, so I omit discussion of that.
Orbital motion around a celestial body has the following property: the plane of the orbit goes through the centre of gravitational attraction. That means the plane of the orbit is such that the centre of gravitational attraction is in the plane of the orbit. It follows: the intersection of the plane of the orbit and the surface of the Earth is a great circle.
The ground track of an orbiting object follows the point on the surface that is straight beneath the orbiting object. ('Straight beneath' is where the line from the satellite to Earth's centre intersects the Earth's surface.)
Now visualize an orbit that is along a plane that is inclined relative to the equatorial plane, for instance, at an angle of $60^\circ$, a pretty high latitude. Now, visualize the ground track of that satellite.
We pick a moment in the orbit where the ground track moves parallel to the local latitude line. Pick the angular velocity of the satellite such that the ground track point moves in west-to-east direction relative to the rotating Earth. A great circle that touches a latitude line bends away from that latitude line towards the Equator.
Now, the more interesting case: again, a moment in the orbit where the ground track point moves parallel to the local latitude line. This time, we pick the angular velocity of the satellite such that the ground track point moves in east-to-west direction relative to the rotating Earth. Then, the ground track point will proceed away from the latitude line towards the Equator.
That is why a bullet that is fired in a direction parallel to the local latitude line ends up deviating from that latitude line.
Incidentally, note the contrast:
An air mass that is moving in west-to-east direction tends to swing wide. Air mass moving in east-to-west direction tends to be pulled to the inside of the latitude line because there is a surplus of centripetal force. But a ballistic object will have a ground track along a great circle, and a great circle bends away from a latitude line that it touches either way, both in west-to-east direction and in east-to-west direction.

Thanks for the detailed answer! Regarding this: "the motion of a buoyant object will not be the same as that of a ballistic object because the buoyant object is subject to both gravity and buoyancy force, whereas the motion of a ballistic is affected by gravity only." I am trying to understand the change in latitude of a fired bullet. Your explanation of air being pushed up or down due to buoyancy makes perfect sense; however, how can I then understand why a bullet fired East or West changes latitude? Thanks!

@Johnlpmark I have added discussion to the answer, for bullet fired East or West

@Johnlpmark To clarify: I had actually overlooked that in the opening paragraph you are asking about the expected motion of a projectile that has been fired (hence asking about ballistics). The picture in the question suggests meteorological context, and further on in the question the resources mentioned are about wind. On the subject of ballistics: there is more material, illustrated with animations, on my own website. See: Ballistics

Thanks! Your projectile addition makes a lot of sense. Based on your answer, I have edited the question with a new diagram. Can you please check it?

@Johnlpmark For the expected trajectory of a bullet there are several relevant factors, the diagrams you created feature only a single one of those factors. General remark: my understanding is that bullets travel so fast that there is negligable rotation-of-Earth-effect (not personal experience; I have never done any firing-bullets-at-a-target). It could be that crossbow darts travel slow enough, and group well enough, to see an effect. Given the Earth's rotation: the target is a moving target: on northern hemisphere: firing west or east: to hit the target you have to aim to the left of it

The Coriolis effect becomes relevant (and well-documented) when shooting at distances of 1 km and above. And even at 1 km the offset is less than 1 m. But significant Coriolis force still exists, and it becomes exponentially more important as the flight time of the bullet increases with either a longer distance or a faster velocity.
Indeed my diagrams ignore many other factors such as air resistance. Apart from the effect of summing velocities (bullet+earth), and the oblate shape of Earth, are there any other effects related to East-West Coriolis specifically?

The Earth is not an exact sphere, but more of an oblate spheroid, as depicted in the diagram below, and this has important consequences.

One consequence is that the gravitational force (dashed blue vector) does not point directly at the centre of the Earth, and neither is it exactly normal to the surface of the Earth. This means the gravitational force has a tangential component (solid blue vector) that acts towards the pole. (The long black dashed line is the tangent to the Earth's surface at the point under consideration.) If the Earth were an exact sphere, there would be no tangential component of the gravitational force acting towards the pole. The black circle is just there to compare the relative lengths of the opposing tangential vector components. Just to be clear, $m$ is a test particle that can be thought of as a representative small ball that is free to move on the surface of an idealised version of the Earth with a perfectly smooth surface. All forces mentioned are those acting on the test particle itself.
The centrifugal force (dashed red vector) has a component (solid red vector) that is tangential to the surface and acts towards the equator. The two tangential vectors ordinarily cancel out, and an object at rest on the surface does not have a tendency to move either North or South. Now, if a block of air happens to be moving from West to East, the velocity of this block of air is added to the tangential motion of the Earth's surface due to its rotation, and this increases the centrifugal force and its tangential component on the block of air. Consequently, there is a net force towards the equator on an East-moving block of air.
Conversely, if the block of air is moving from East to West, its motion detracts from the tangential velocity and decreases the centrifugal force. As a result, the tangential component towards the equator is reduced, resulting in a net force acting towards the nearest pole, on a West-moving block of air.
The oblateness and change in magnitude of the force vectors have been exaggerated in the diagrams for clarity. It is also worth noting that a large block of air has a centre of gravity that is significantly higher than the surface of the Earth. As a result, the gravitational force acting on it is less than at the surface, and the centrifugal force is greater. This creates a tendency for the large block of air to move from the pole towards the equator even when the block of air has no East/West motion relative to the surface.
Putting it all together:

In the above diagram, there is a low-pressure region in the centre. Higher-pressure air moves towards the low-pressure region due to pressure differential. A small parcel of air that is moving in any direction will be deflected to the right in the Northern hemisphere and the net result is a large body of air that rotates in an anti-clockwise direction. The converse is true in the Southern hemisphere.

I submit there is an ambiguity in the answer that is worth addressing. In the case of the rotating Earth the expression 'centrifugal force' is by most authors used to refer to the centrifugal term in the equation of motion (for motion relative to the rotating Earth). That is: in this context most authors use the expression 'centrifugal force' to refer to something that cannot change; it's a given.  I think it is worthwhile to mention explicitly that the increasing and decreasing 'centrifugal force' that you describe is not the one associated with the rotating system.

I am talking about the forces acting on the test particle m and if m is moving the centrifugal force is not constant. Only the centrifugal force of the Earth's surface at that point is constant. If the surface velocity of the Earth's surface at the equator is 465 m/s  and if the "test particle" is a jet flying at 465 m/s in the Westerly direction, there would be no centrifugal force acting on the jet. Note we are talking about blocks of air with motion relative to the surface of the Earth.

@Cleonis The Wikipedia article on the Eötvös effect explicitly mentions the change in centrifugal force in the first paragraph. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_effect

A rocket flying fast enough around the equator can have so much centrifugal force acting on it that it effectively become "weightless". This is essentially how satellites orbit. Satellites would fall out the sky, if the centrifugal force was a constant and independent of motion relative to the surface of the Earth.

Side note: the wikipedia article about the Eötvös effect. I started that article in 2006. I checked the history: my last involvement was in december 2008. (I'm no longer active on wikipedia.) The remark about centrifugal acceleration was added in 2010.  In my opinion the wording of that section is awkward. We have: an object that is co-rotating with the Earth is subject to centripetal acceleration, towards the axis of rotation. (An exhaustive acceleration listing would proceed to the acceleration associated with the Earth's orbit around the Sun, but that one is already way smaller.)

" We have: an object that is co-rotating with the Earth is subject to centripetal acceleration, towards the axis of rotation." An object that is moving from West to East relative to the surface of the Earth can not be described as co-rotating with the Earth.

The Coriolis effect and the Eötvös effect only deflect blocks of air that are initially moving relative to the surface of the Earth and have no affect on blocks of air that are rest with respect to the surface of the Earth (at low altitude). Consequently the Coriolis effect and the Eötvös effects, do not apply to objects that are co-rotating with the Earth.

I understand you example, but not its consequences. As I understand the equations, the Coriolis force is equal in all directions on the tangential plane. Your explanation seems to rely on the fact that gravity has a default component that pulls objects towards the poles due to the oblate shape of the Earth. Does this imply that perfect spheres do not have a Coriolis force that is equal in all directions on the tangential plane?

Yes, the tangential force on a perfect rotating sphere would deflect everything, moving or otherwise towards the equator.  It is this tendency for matter to head towards the equator that transforms any non rigid rotating sphere into an oblate spheroid where the gravitational component directed to the poles, matches the centrifugal component directed towards the equator at every point on the surface. It is not a coincidence.

P.S. There are no perfectly rigid bodies and no rotating planets or stellar bodies that are perfect spheres.

You use a lot of imprecise language that may be leading to problems. I'll review those and get to the question.
Before that, though, I'll use "Coriolis Force" to refer to the velocity-dependent inertia force in any rotating reference frame and "Coriolis Effect" to mean the Coriolis Force in a coordinate system that is fixed and tangent to the Earth's surface, let's say ENU (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates). [note, I'll use $\hat E_{\phi}, \hat N_{\phi}, \hat U_{\phi}$ to indicate the unit vectors of the coordinates system, at a latitude of $\phi$, if needed.]
First, the "North-South" component. That sounds like $F_N$ (North component of Coriolis force), but you describe $v_N$ (North component of test mass velocity) and then say the object retains its angular velocity. The Earth has an angular velocity, and the object does not. The object has North velocity, which in the northern hemisphere causes an $F_E$ force per your description: the instantaneous ENU coordinates are losing eastward velocity in an ECI (Earth Centered Inertial) frame.
The Eötvös effect is described as a reduction (increase) in Earth's gravity, $g$, in a ship or bullet train for a modern version, moving east (west).
I'll stick to a $300 \ \text{mph}$ bullet train running along the equator, with gravity acting on a test mass in the train.
The change of $g$ is not the Coriolis Force because the test mass is not moving in the reference frame of the train. For east (west) train motion, the test mass is moving in ECI at $1300$ ($700$) $\text{mph}$, so the centrifugal force (from $F=v^2/R$, with $R=a$ from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) in the train frames is $5.4$ ($1.6$) $\text{milli-g}$, which manifests as lower (higher) gravity in the trains' respective frames.
Now, in an ECF frame, the centrifugal forces on the east and west test masses are the same since they depend only on the radius, and the Coriolis Force is vertical, so it subtracts from or adds to $g$. Note, here, the presence of the train doesn't matter. All we care about is the test masses' East/West speed.
Regarding the North/South component of the Coriolis Force, which is caused by East/West velocity, I don't think bringing in fluids is going to help.
Since you've already understood the Coriolis effect leading to a vertical force at the equator, it is just caused by East/West motion in the ECF frame.
Note that $\vec v_E$ is perpendicular $\Omega$ in this case, therefore the Coriolis force
$$ \vec F_C = -2m(\vec \Omega \times \vec v) $$
has to be orthogonal to both $\vec \Omega$ and $\vec v$ at the equator, which leaves one alignment along where to move: up/down.
Now imagine the train is latitude $\phi = 45^{\circ}\,\text{North}$: in ECF, nothing has changed about the Coriolis Force. Yes, the train is moving in a smaller circle around the axis ($\rho = R_{\otimes}/\sqrt 2$), but that doesn't change the Coriolis Force --only the velocity matters and that is the same.
It still points "up" in the equator's definition of up.
What has changed is the orientation of the local ENU frame. What is the equator's "up" is now:
$$ \hat U_0 = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\Big(\hat U_{45N} - \hat N_{45 N}\Big), $$
so there is a southerly component to the force.
There is also a vertical component. Note that the vertical component of the Coriolis Effect is ignored there when considering the Coriolis Effect on weather.

Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, and I'm sorry there is no diplomatic way to say this, I understood nothing of what you wrote. At the extreme, I have never encountered these: "Ω" "R⊗" "U^0"; however, more to the point I already trust that all the formulas are good models. But I need those formulas translated to plain terms and "imprecise" language. Can you please explain this without any symbols, numbers, abbreviations, or equations? Specifically, while you gave an example for Eotvos effect, you relied on equations for the East-West effect, whereas I need another practical example.

U hat is the up coordinate unit vector. Omega is the angular velocity of earth. R is the radial coordinate of the test mass. and without the cross product, I don't the Coriolis force can make sense. Just remember all inertial forces, including gravity, appear because of the choice of coordinates, and: they are just as real or fictitious as gravity.

To move in a circular motion, you expect to have to apply a centripetal force of $M \omega^2r$. This is the same whether you want to rotate clockwise or anticlockwise.
Say a mass of $1 \ \text{kg}$ ($M=1$) wants to rotate at a radius of $1 \ \text{m}$ ($r=1$) at $10 \ \text{rad/s}$ ($\omega=10$). The required centripetal force is $100 \ \text{N}$ ($1 \times 10^2 \times 1$) regardless of the direction of rotation.
But say your frame of reference is already rotating clockwise at $1 \ \text{rad/s}$. To keep the mass stationary relative to the frame of reference, it would need to hold on with a $1 \ \text{N}$ force (otherwise, the perceived $1 \ \text{N}$ centrifugal force will make it fly outwards).
Now rotate the mass at $10 \ \text{rad/s}$ relative to the frame of reference:

A $10 \ \text{rad/s}$ clockwise rotation would be an absolute rotation of $11 \ \text{rad/s}$, requiring a force of $121 \ \text{N}$ ($120 \ \text{N}$ increase compared to that required to remain stationary relative to the frame of reference).
A $10 \ \text{rad/s}$ anticlockwise rotation would be an absolute rotation of $9 \ \text{rad/s}$, requiring a force of $81 \ \text{N}$ ($80 \ \text{N}$ increase compared to that required to remain stationary relative to the frame of reference).

So, in this rotating frame of reference, the required centripetal force is different for clockwise and anticlockwise rotation ($120 \ \text{N}$ vs $80 \ \text{N}$).
Moving East-West or West-East on Earth is similar to this situation.  The difference is that we don't perceive the centripetal force because it is in the opposite direction to gravity, and the gravity force is always larger (i.e. we don’t need to hold on to the earth to avoid being flung outwards because the gravity force is always large enough to take care of this).
Instead, we perceive the centripetal force as reduced gravity.
